# Qt Model View, update view on loosely coupled Model and Data

Tags: qt, model-view-controller, model

This question is an upgrade on the following two questions:

- [Qt Model View pattern, design choices for connecting Model with Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19704680/qt-model-view-pattern-design-choices-for-connecting-model-with-data)
- [Qt Model-View update view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19707067/qt-model-view-update-view)

Here is the situation:

[image]

MODEL has a pointer to the SERVER (SERVER represents [Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adeqg.png)) through which it gets the required data and formats them into `QStrings`, so that the VIEW can understand them. The model keeps no internal copies of the `QList`, it accesses it directly and converts the requ `QTcpSocket *` to `QStrings` in the `QVariant QAbstractItemModel::data` method.

However the list of sockets can change without the Model or View knowing about it if a new connection to the SERVER is established. In that case another `QTcpSOcket *` is appended to the SERVERs QList.

How to notify the View on the Model/Data change?

- Call `QAbstractItemModel::reset()` from the SERVER on each new connection. I consider this bad for it requires to modify the SERVER for the needs of the MODEL in which case i could of just had the MODEL and the SERVER as a single entity.
- `connect(&server, QTcpServer::newConnection, &model, &StationListModel::reset)`  Try to connect the SERVER and MODEL via Signals and Slots. However, `&StationListModel::reset` ISN'T a slot, so i believe this isn't the right way.

I would like to hear which of the mentioned approaches (if any) is considered appropriate in the given situation. And is the insisting on MODEL-SERVER loose coupling a bad design choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how it should be done:

1. Create signals in SERVER that notify about data change (or use existing `QTcpServer::newConnection` signal if it is sufficient).
2. Create a slot (or slots) in your model class and connect SERVER's signal to this slot.
3. In the slot's implementation emit signals or call internal methods (e.g. `beginInsertRows`, `endInsertRows`) or just reset the model to notify the view about new changes.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to incrementally append new items to your view, I would do this in the following way:

In your model class

```
// A slot
void MyModel::onNewConnection()
{
    // Append new socket to the list QList<QTcpSocket *>
    m_socketList.puch_back(new QTcpSocket);
    // Update the model.
    insertRow(0);
}

// Virtual function
bool MyModel::insertRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex &parent)
{
    if (!parent.isValid()) {
        // We need to append a row to the bottom of the view.
        int rows = rowCount() - 1;

        beginInsertRows(parent, rows, rows);
        // Do nothing, but just inform view(s) that the internal data has changed
        // and these rows should be added.
        endInsertRows();
        return true;
    }
    return QAbstractItemModel::insertRows(row, count, parent);
}
```

Somewhere in your code

```
[..]
connect(&server, QTcpServer::newConnection, &model, &StationListModel::onNewConnection)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I would like to share what I do when I was working on the exactly same issue.
If you are placing the server pointer into the model implementation and you get all the model information from the `QList< QTcpSocket *>` use this connection:

```
connect(server, SIGNAL(newConnection()), this, SIGNAL(modelReset()));
```